# Trailing Slash Issue With htaccess and Sub-domain Rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following in my htaccess

```
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

1. How do I append a trailing slash to the URL using the above code snippet?

Comment: **You might want to make a new question for your second question item** as it may be completely unrelated to your first question depending on the circumstances of how the domain and sub domain are configured so I will go ahead and answer your first item. Does orange.domain.com and domain.com share the same DocumentRoot can you be certain of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to your 1st question item, you can use the follow to add the trailing slash:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
```

Basically what it does is, it checks if the php file referenced to that address exists, if it does and the URL does not have a ending slash it adds it.

The full code would look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R,L]

# add a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I will go ahead and make a new question for my second question. Thanks a lot. You gave me a good answer that I needed. It really saved me.

Comment: glad it worked for you, let me know when you make the new question I Will check it out.

Comment: Here is a link to the second question. I also referenced the htaccess here to avoid any redirect conflicts. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25843373/sub-domain-redirect-using-htaccess

Comment: I cannot find your answer to the question I referenced here as you demanded `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25843373/sub-domain-redirect-using-htaccess`Did you delete it?

Comment: I am also experiencing an issue here. A url as `https://www.url.com/me/you/forgot/f5f7d7` automatically gets `.php` appended to it. Why is that and how can I handle the issue?