# Sub-domain Redirect Using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am working on a project that requires rewriting a URL like

> https://orange.url.com

to

> https://www.url.com/?s=orange

I need assistance on how to churn out htaccess to handle this task.
PS: Please not that I already have the following in my htaccess handling some rewriting for me.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R,L]

# add a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Do you have `www` and other subdomains (like `orange` and so on if you have a wildcard) pointing to the same server document root ?

Comment: How do you want to handle `https://orange.url.com/anything`?

Comment: @Prix `Orange` in the URL is only a slog from a category name created and inserted into the database.
@anubhava I wish to handle that using $_GET as usual that is rewriting something like `https://orange.url.com/subcategory/otherfruits/` to `https://www.url.com/?s=orange&c=subcategory&g=otherfruits`
@JustinIurman I have not appended `www` to my URL but if it's a good rule of thumb to have it appended, I won't mind integrating that so that `https://www.url.com?s=orange` will resolve to same link as `https://www.orange.url.com`

Comment: @Prix I am actually needing a wildcard for this. The subdomains are not actual subdomains (no physical folders) for now. 

Actual sub-domains in different folders but in same root folder with the other website files will still come in place too; something like `https://store.url.com` having an actual folder of `store`. I hope you understand what I mean here.

Comment: @Prix, where's your answer gone to?

Comment: @JustinIurman You got clues on how I can solve this puzzle here? I'm really having some hard times fixing this and I have some uprising issues with the current rewrites which I'll talk more about after this sub-domain rewrite.

Comment: What i initially asked you was if `www.domain.com` and `orange.domain.com` (actually `*.domain.com` since it's a wildcard) are pointing to the same document root server ?

Comment: @JustinIurman Yes they are. Sorry I didn't figure out that was what you were requiring of me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put this code in your htaccess (which has to be in your root folder)

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To internally forward http://xxx.domain.com to http://www.domain.com/?s=xxx
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.).+?)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?s=%1 [L]

# To internally forward http://xxx.domain.com/yyy/ to http://www.domain.com/?s=xxx&c=yyy
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.).+?)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ index.php?s=%1&c=$1 [L]

# To internally forward http://xxx.domain.com/yyy/zzz/ to http://www.domain.com/?s=xxx&c=yyy&g=zzz
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.).+?)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ index.php?s=%1&c=$1&g=$2 [L]

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(.+?)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R,L]

# add a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo/ to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the leads. Before I apply, I'd like you to help with this other issue. A url as `https://www.url.com/me/you/forgot/f5f7d7` used for either user activation or forgot password feature (since they have the same url structure) is meant to rewrite to `https://www.url.com/me/you/forgot.php?key=f5f7d7` but it never does. Rather it says "page isn't redirecting properly" and other forms of errors when I try tweaking it. Sometimes it adds a ".php" after the "?key=f5f7d7.php/" Please can you help with that too so I can apply all at once and give you feedback. Thanks in advance

Comment: That's because of your last rule to hide/rewrite `php` extension. The fastest solution would be to add a specific rule for that (in the beginning): `RewriteRule ^me/you/forgot/([^/]+)/?$ /me/you/forgot.php?key=$1 [L]`

Comment: Thanks buddy. I'll implement all as fast as I can then report back here with issues if any else I accept your answer. Thanks a lot. I will be back here soon. Give me some implementation time.\

Comment: I've been testing out and working around this but not gotten it to work. `http://xxx.domain.com` does not forward to `http://www.domain.com/?s=xxx` Been at it for a while now and I've even tried another set of conditions and still failed. Can we get into a chat if possible?

Comment: What result do you get for which url(s) ? Any error ?

Comment: It returns a "Server not found". Following this rule `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ index.php?s=%1&c=$1 [L]` I made a different page `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ fruits.php?s=%1&c=$1 [L]` and put a simple echo "OK" inside to know when the page is read but I never seem to get to fruits.php. Can we go on a chat so I show you the actual url?

Comment: Sure we can have a chat

Comment: Let's connect here please http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61707/sub-domain-redirect-using-htaccess

Comment: The wildcard domain issue has been resolved now by the hosting company. We can finish up where we left out if you're free